# How do i read the value returned by a method in my smart contract in web3j

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, web3j

I'm following a tutorial in which the instructor is calling `contract.getConuter().send` this returns the value of the counter on smart-contract but in my case, it's returning `TranscriptReciept` object.

**Solidity Contract**

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;
contract HelloWorld {
    uint256 counter = 5;

    function add() public {  //increases counter by 1
        counter++;
    }

    function subtract() public { //decreases counter by 1
        counter--;
    }

    function getCounter() public view returns (uint256) {
        return counter;
    }

}
```

**Trying to get the value of `getCounter()`**

```js
   val identityContract = HelloWorld_sol_HelloWorld.load(
            deployedContractAddress,
            web3j,
            getCredentialsFromPrivateKey(),
            DefaultGasProvider.GAS_PRICE,
            DefaultGasProvider.GAS_LIMIT
        )

        Log.d(TAG, "counter Result:  ${identityContract.getCounter().sendAsync().get()}")
```

Instead of getting the counter result i'm getting following output, insane.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after doing it in different ways now i'm able to read the value returned by the function in smartcontract using web3j.

First create `Function` type varible from `org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Function` like this

```
  val function = Function(
            "getCounter", //make sure this name is same as your function name in solidity file.
            Collections.emptyList(),
            listOf(object : TypeReference<Uint?>() {})
        )
        val encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(function)
```

then make a request

```
   val response = web3j.ethCall(
            Transaction.createEthCallTransaction(null, deployedContractAddress, encodedFunction),
            DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST
        )
            .sendAsync().get()

        val results =
            FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(response.value, function.outputParameters)
       
        val preValue = results[0] as Uint

        Log.d(TAG, "loadContract: Counter Value: ${preValue.value}")
```

And boom it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Can you show us the code of that smart contract?

It is possible that the `getCounter` function is declared as non pure/view, and the `.send` is actually sending your transaction to be mined because maybe it will alter the state of the smart contract and not simply send you the `counter`. So, it will probably update the counter and then return it. That's why you get a Receipt. The smart contract cannot return you the new value of the counter right away because the transaction hasn't been mined, and you need to wait for it to be mined, so you get a receipt and you can use it to wait for the transaction to be mined and then try to get the new counter value.

Probably doing something like `await transcriptReciept.wait(1)` to wait one confirmation (for your transaction to be mined in a block). Then you can try to access the new counter value with `await contract.counter()` in case the `counter` state variable is declared as public or external.

When you `send` a transaction that will modify the state, your transaction will be broadcasted through the network for validation, will be mined and the block containing it will be broadcasted through the network.

When you use `call` to execute your transaction, let's say that your transaction will only read from the state of the smart contract and not modify it, then any node can provide you that information, and that transaction doesn't need to be mined, nor it needs to be broadcasted through the network. That's why you receive the result right away when you call a smart contract function that is declared as `view` or `pure` since it will not modify the state.

Share the smart contract code and the javascript script to see if that is actually what is doing.

I was able to reproduce it with Javascript using `web3`:

```js
const Web3 = require("web3");

const web3 = new Web3("http://127.0.0.1:7545");

const abi = [
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "add",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "subtract",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "getCounter",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
];

const helloWorldContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
  abi,
  "0xA253E8C4F4cA396feefF080e5f61EDB0952bF28e",
  {
    from: "0xD743192B367b781b8fedacf4a77A2CBA6e58C15d",
  }
);

// With `send` it returns a transaction receipt, with `call` it returns the value right away.
const response = helloWorldContract.methods.getCounter().send();

response.then((response) => {
  console.log("response: ", response);
});
```

With `.send()`, it returns the transaction receipt:

```js
response:  {
  transactionHash: '0x4dbc1cc7d6115af7c9492c6bc5fec7aa6c39b71b64af947bab4e0e266454a547',
  transactionIndex: 0,
  blockHash: '0xa9fe04aaaa95dff2856fbc59f8d38b2ae190f6589bfec9075a4fac28eb570cff',
  blockNumber: 9,
  from: '0xd743192b367b781b8fedacf4a77a2cba6e58c15d',
  to: '0xa253e8c4f4ca396feeff080e5f61edb0952bf28e',
  gasUsed: 22223,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 22223,
  contractAddress: null,
  status: true,
  logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  events: {}
}
```

With `.call`, it returns the value:

````js
const Web3 = require("web3");

const web3 = new Web3("http://127.0.0.1:7545");

const abi = [
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "add",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "subtract",
    outputs: [],
    stateMutability: "nonpayable",
    type: "function",
  },
  {
    inputs: [],
    name: "getCounter",
    outputs: [
      {
        internalType: "uint256",
        name: "",
        type: "uint256",
      },
    ],
    stateMutability: "view",
    type: "function",
  },
];

const helloWorldContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
  abi,
  "0xA253E8C4F4cA396feefF080e5f61EDB0952bF28e",
  {
    from: "0xD743192B367b781b8fedacf4a77A2CBA6e58C15d",
  }
);

// With `send` it returns a transaction receipt, with `call` it returns the value right away.
const response = helloWorldContract.methods.getCounter().call();

response.then((response) => {
  console.log("response: ", response);
});

```js
response:  5
````

So, try changing `contract.getCounter.send()` with `contract.getCounter.call()`.

For `Web3j`, try this: https://docs.web3j.io/4.8.7/smart_contracts/interacting_with_smart_contract/#calling-constant-methods

"Constant methods are those that read a value in a smart contract, and do not alter the state of the smart contract. These methods are available with the same method signature as the smart contract they were generated from:"

```
Type result = contract.someMethod(<param1>, ...).send();
```

Comment: thank @jeremy for you detailed answer, I've add code above please have a look. Thank you

Comment: What is the programming language you are using? In Javascript, we could probably `await` and that would unwrap the result. I'm not sure if the programming language you are using has something similar or if it's sync by default.

Comment: I'm using kotlin, its sync by default.

Comment: Actually i'm concerned with the result returned by `contract.getCounter.send()`

Comment: Check my update to the answer. Try: `contract.getCounter.call()`.

Comment: yes thank you but in web3j i don't have `call()` i only have `send()`, `sendAsync()` and `flowable()` :(