# counter value is always 0 in web3j

Tags: web3j

I've checked the following `getCounter()` method in Remix, it's doing what its supposed to do.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;


struct User{
    uint counter;
    bool isParticipant;
}

contract Parcel{
    mapping(address =>User) public users;


    function enroll() public payable{
        User storage user = users[msg.sender];
        require(user.isParticipant==false, 'You are already a participant');
        users[msg.sender] = User(0,true);
    }

    function increment() public payable{
        User storage user = users[msg.sender];
        require(user.isParticipant==true, 'You are not a participant');
        user.counter+=1;
    }

    function getCounter() public view returns(uint){
         User storage user = users[msg.sender];
        return user.counter;
    }
```

But when I call `getCounter()` using web3j in my app, it returns 0 always.
What could be the problem here?

Following is the method to read value from smartcontract

```
val web3j = Web3j.build(HttpService(Constants.ALCHEMY_API))

                val function = Function(
                    "getCounter", //make sure this name is same as your function name in solidity file.
                    Collections.emptyList(),
                    listOf(object : TypeReference<Uint?>() {})
                )
                val encodedFunction = FunctionEncoder.encode(function)


                val response = web3j.ethCall(
                    Transaction.createEthCallTransaction(null, contractAddress, encodedFunction),
                    DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST
                )
                    .sendAsync().get()

                val results =
                    FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(response.value, function.outputParameters)

                val preValue = results[0] as Uint

                Log.d(TAG, "Contract Address: $contractAddress")
                Log.d(TAG, "loadContract: Counter Value: ${preValue.value}")
```

Comment: why aren't you using the java contract wrapper and then calling the method instead of using Transaction.createEthCallTransaction?
https://docs.web3j.io/4.8.7/getting_started/deploy_interact_smart_contracts/

Comment: I tried but that didn't worked for me. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/133944/how-do-i-read-the-value-returned-by-a-method-in-my-smart-contract-in-web3j/133963#133963

Comment: is java contract wrapper working on your side?

Comment: @MajdTL if i follow the link you sent `contract.method().send()` returns transaction receipt which i don't want.

Comment: Yes .send() is for transactions. I can try the contract wrapper for you tomorrow

Comment: HI @MajdTL, i have updated my web3j client now i the method is returning the right value. But i'm struct in another problem, i've a struct in my .sol file. but when i created java wrapper class using web3j the struct in java wrapper is not recognized.

Comment: Have you ever used a .sol file having struct in java wrapper?

Comment: I'm able to generate the java class wrapper , you can find it here https://gist.github.com/MajdT51/e4bf2266c5d061c1bc561ed77335eade

load the contract and then use the getCounter method like described here https://docs.web3j.io/4.8.7/smart_contracts/interacting_with_smart_contract/#calling-constant-methods

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138797/discussion-between-shoaib-khalid-and-majd-tl).